# Switch parts of adjacent lines

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have this code that switch lines up/down:

```
;; Moving a line up or down
(defun move-text-internal (arg)
  (cond
   ((and mark-active transient-mark-mode)
    (if (> (point) (mark))
        (exchange-point-and-mark))
    (let ((column (current-column))
          (text (delete-and-extract-region (point) (mark))))
      (forward-line arg)
      (move-to-column column t)
      (set-mark (point))
      (insert text)
      (exchange-point-and-mark)
      (setq deactivate-mark nil)))
   (t
    (let ((column (current-column)))
      (beginning-of-line)
      (when (or (> arg 0) (not (bobp)))
        (forward-line)
        (when (or (< arg 0) (not (eobp)))
          (transpose-lines arg))
        (forward-line -1))
      (move-to-column column t)))))

(defun move-text-down (arg)
  "Move region (transient-mark-mode active) or current line
  arg lines down."
  (interactive "*p")
  (move-text-internal arg))
(global-set-key [M-S-down] 'move-text-down)

(defun move-text-up (arg)
  "Move region (transient-mark-mode active) or current line
  arg lines up."
  (interactive "*p")
  (move-text-internal (- arg)))
(global-set-key [M-S-up]   'move-text-up)
```

I was wondering if it is possible to tweak the move-text-internal function so it is possible to move part of line "after cursor" up or down.

Here is an example:

Before:

```
A X B W
Q E O P
```

If cursor was after X on the first line, after M-S-down:

```
A X O P
Q E B W
```

UPDATE:
Thanks to Jordan Biondo for the the his code and function.
I tweaked it to keep line moving as long as you keep invoking the command.

```
(defun flip-text (&optional arg)
  "Flip the text from point to the end of the current line with the text
in the next line from the same column to the end of the next line.
With a prefix arg, flip text with the line above the current."
  (interactive "p")
  (save-excursion
    (let ((tt (delete-and-extract-region (point) (point-at-eol)))
          (c (current-column)))
      (forward-line arg)
      (move-to-column c)
      (insert tt)
      (let ((ot (delete-and-extract-region (point) (point-at-eol))))
        (forward-line (- arg))
        (goto-char (point-at-eol))
        (insert ot)
    ))
    )
  (previous-line (- arg))
  )
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-z") (lambda ()
                  (interactive)
                  (flip-text 1)))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-c") (lambda ()
                  (interactive)
                  (flip-text -1)))
```

Comment: Is there a reason you want the code tweaked instead of writing a new function?

Comment: The code above is taken from basic-edit-library. It is efficient and optimized.
I believe utilizing the same function would be a better idea than starting a new one. Specially, that what I am asking for is very close to what the function is already doing.

Comment: are you looking to move the text down/up multiple lines when you do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do what you specified but does not do multiple lines.

```lisp
(defun flip-text-to-eol (&optional up)
  "Flip the text from point to the end of the current line with the text
in the next line from the same column to the end of the next line.

With a prefix arg, flip text with the line above the current."
  (interactive "P")
  (save-excursion
    (let ((tt (delete-and-extract-region (point) (point-at-eol)))
          (c (current-column)))
      (forward-line (if up -1 1))
      (move-to-column c)
      (insert tt)
      (let ((ot (delete-and-extract-region (point) (point-at-eol))))
        (forward-line (if up 1 -1))
        (goto-char (point-at-eol))
        (insert ot)))))
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice! It does exactly what I want except that I would like it to behave like the code I have up, I want to be able to move that part of the code multiple lines up or down.
I think a mix between your code and the move-text-internal function should do it. But I am not sure how.

Comment: Ok. Figured it out and updated my question with a tweaked version that does exactly what I want. Thanks Jordon.